# WSO2 Identity server not able to consume custom federated authenticator

Tags: java, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to use my own java application based on oauth2 as a federated authenticator in WSO2 IS. I have implemented the following things

1. created IDP which points to my java auth application with required client-id and secret key
2. created service provider which uses this IDP as federated authenticator
3. service provider also has oauth2 as inbound authenticator

However, wso2-is is not passing on my auth request to federated authenticator and is using local auth only to generate tokens. I do not wish to create my userbase on wso2 so local auth is not an option for me.

Pls find debug logs below and let me know where i am going wrong.

> [2019-01-11 12:28:41,046] DEBUG -  LOAD IMMEDIATE started {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,046] DEBUG -  Started loading 3000 jobs from db {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,046] DEBUG -  Beginning a new transaction {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,048] DEBUG -  Committing on org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.GeronimoTransactionManager@f596317... {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,048] DEBUG -   Transaction is successfully committed {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.openjpa.HumanTaskDAOConnectionFactoryImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,048] DEBUG -  loaded 0 jobs from db {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,048] DEBUG -  LOAD IMMEDIATE complete {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,371] DEBUG -  Created singleton instance for org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,371] DEBUG -  Get first priority handler for the given handler list. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,371] DEBUG -  Get first priority handler : DefaultAuthenticationManager(org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.AuthenticationManager) {org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.service.handler.HandlerManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,374] DEBUG -  Executing OAuth client authenticators. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuthClientAuthnService}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,374] DEBUG -  Retrieving registered OAuth client authenticator list. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuthClientAuthnService}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,374] DEBUG -  Evaluating canAuthenticate of authenticator : BasicOAuthClientCredAuthenticator {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuthClientAuthnService}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,375] DEBUG -  Basic auth credentials exists as Authorization header. Hence returning true. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.BasicAuthClientAuthenticator}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,375] DEBUG -  BasicOAuthClientCredAuthenticator authenticator can handle incoming request. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuthClientAuthnService}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,375] DEBUG -  Authenticator BasicOAuthClientCredAuthenticator can authenticate the client request.  Hence trying to evaluate authentication {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuthClientAuthnService}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,375] DEBUG -  Authorization header exists. Hence validating whether body params also present {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.BasicAuthClientAuthenticator}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,375] DEBUG -  Authenticating client : 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa with client secret. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.BasicAuthClientAuthenticator}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,419] DEBUG -  Client credentials were fetched from the database. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,419] DEBUG -  Successfully authenticated the client with client id : 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,419] DEBUG -  Client credentials were added to the cache for client id : 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,419] DEBUG -  Authentication result from OAuth client authenticator BasicOAuthClientCredAuthenticator is : true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuthClientAuthnService}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,419] DEBUG -  Setting OAuth client authentication context to request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.client.authn.filter.OAuthClientAuthenticatorProxy}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,421] DEBUG -  Oauth App validation success for consumer key: 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.util.EndpointUtil}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,422] DEBUG -  Access Token request received for Client ID 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa, User ID Dev, Scope : [] and Grant Type : password {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,422] DEBUG -  Triggering access token pre issuer listeners for client: 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Retrieving 0 Scope validators registered for OAuth appId 1 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dao.OAuthAppDAO}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Oauth App validation success for consumer key: 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Is listener enabled from configs: true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Is consent enabled system wide: true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Listener is enabled and consent is enabled system wide. Hence returning true for isEnabled {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Is listener enabled from configs: true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Is consent enabled system wide: true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Listener is enabled and consent is enabled system wide. Hence returning true for isEnabled {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Is listener enabled from configs: true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,423] DEBUG -  Is consent enabled system wide: true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,424] DEBUG -  Listener is enabled and consent is enabled system wide. Hence returning true for isEnabled {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,424] DEBUG -  Loading Basic Application Data of DemoService {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,424] DEBUG -  ApplicationID: 2 ApplicationName: DemoService UserName: admin TenantDomain: carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,424] DEBUG -  Reading Clients of Application 2 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,424] DEBUG -  Reading Steps of Application 2 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,425] DEBUG -  Reading Claim Mappings of Application 2 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,425] DEBUG -  Local Claim: http://wso2.org/claims/username SPClaim: username {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,425] DEBUG -  Local Claim: http://wso2.org/claims/identity/askPassword SPClaim: password {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,425] DEBUG -  Reading Role Mapping of Application 2 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,431] DEBUG -  Using local cache {org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,432] DEBUG -  Is listener enabled from configs: true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,433] DEBUG -  Is consent enabled system wide: true {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,433] DEBUG -  Listener is enabled and consent is enabled system wide. Hence returning true for isEnabled {org.wso2.carbon.identity.consent.mgt.listener.ConsentDeletionAppMgtListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,433] DEBUG -  Retrieved service provider: DemoService for client: 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa, scope: oauth2, tenant: carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,433] DEBUG -  Retrieved tenant id: -1234 for tenant domain: carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,433] DEBUG -  Retrieved user store manager for tenant id: -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,433] DEBUG -  Pre authenticator is called in IdentityMgtEventListener {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,434] DEBUG -  Using local cache {org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,434] DEBUG -  Cache entry not found for Identity Provider LOCAL. Fetching entry from DB {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,435] DEBUG -  Entry fetched from DB for Identity Provider LOCAL. Updating cache {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,436] DEBUG -  Using local cache {org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,436] DEBUG -  Resolving tenant id from tenant domain {org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,436] DEBUG -  Account disable feature is disabled for tenant :carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountDisableHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,436] DEBUG -  Handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION {org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.handler.AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,436] DEBUG -  PreAuthenticate - AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler for user : Dev@carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.handler.AdminForcedPasswordResetHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,436] DEBUG -  Error while reading user store property CaseInsensitiveUsername. Considering as case sensitive. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityUtil}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,436] DEBUG -  PreAuthenticate {org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery.handler.AccountConfirmationValidationHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,437] DEBUG -  Searching for user Dev {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,437] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,437] DEBUG -  Using local cache {org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,437] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,459] DEBUG -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=person)(uid=Dev)) in SearchBase:  {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,461] DEBUG -  Name in space for Dev is null {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,461] DEBUG -  User: Dev exist: false {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,461] DEBUG -  Cache entry found for Identity Provider LOCAL {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.dao.CacheBackedIdPMgtDAO}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,461] DEBUG -  Cache Key not found for Random Password Container {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.processors.RandomPasswordProcessor}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,462] DEBUG -  Resolving tenant id from tenant domain {org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,463] DEBUG -  Account lock handler is disabled in tenant: carbon.super {org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountLockHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,463] DEBUG -  Authenticating user Dev {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,463] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,463] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,463] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,475] DEBUG -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=person)(uid=Dev)) in SearchBase:  {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,478] DEBUG -  Name in space for Dev is null {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,478] DEBUG -  Searching for user Dev {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,478] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,478] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,484] DEBUG -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=person)(uid=Dev)) in SearchBase:  {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,486] DEBUG -  Name in space for Dev is null {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,486] DEBUG -  User: Dev exist: false {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,486] DEBUG -  User, Dev does not exist in PRIMARY {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.listener.SCIMUserOperationListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,486] DEBUG -  post authenticator is called in IdentityMgtEventListener {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,486] DEBUG -  Searching for user Dev {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,486] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,486] DEBUG -  Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,498] DEBUG -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=person)(uid=Dev)) in SearchBase:  {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,501] DEBUG -  Name in space for Dev is null {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,501] DEBUG -  User: Dev exist: false {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,501] DEBUG -  IdentityMgtEventListener returns since user: Dev not available in current user store domain: PRIMARY {org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,501] DEBUG -  Authentication failure. Wrong username or password is provided. {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,501] DEBUG -  user Dev authenticated: false {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,501] DEBUG -  Error occurred while validating grant {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer}
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2Exception: Authentication failed for Dev
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler.validateUserCredentials(PasswordGrantHandler.java:134)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler.validateGrant(PasswordGrantHandler.java:70)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:225)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:225)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:293)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:89)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
>           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:128)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,503] DEBUG -  Invalid Grant provided by the client Id: 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,503] DEBUG -  OAuth-Error-Code=invalid_grant client-id=98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa grant-type=password scope= {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer}
>   [2019-01-11 12:28:41,503] DEBUG -  Triggering access token post issuer listeners for client: 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer}

Inbound authenticator client id is : 98XLmZC4b27FOjoq1b8qTqoOjrQa

User id (from my user store) is : Dev

My Id Provider Configuration is as below

[image: My Id Provider Configuration]

My Service Provider Configuration is as below

[image: My Service Provider Configuration]

Comment: Are you using password grant to create the access token?

Comment: @senthalan yes i'm trying to use password grant type to generate access token. Password validator and token generator will be my external java application which i want to connect to wso2 as a federated authenticator

Answer (score 0):

To use federated users for the password grant type, you need to customize [PasswordGrantHandler](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-auth-oauth/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth2/token/handlers/grant/PasswordGrantHandler.java). You need to create a new class(lets say `custom.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.CustomPasswordGrantHandler`) extending this and override the validateGrant method. Then make it as an OSGi bundle and deploy in IS_HOME/repository/components/dropins. Also, change the `GrantTypeHandlerImplClass` of the password grant type in IS_HOME/repository/components/conf/identity/identity.xml

```
<SupportedGrantType>
      <GrantTypeName>password</GrantTypeName>
<GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>custom.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.CustomPasswordGrantHandler</GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>
</SupportedGrantType>
```

Comment: This works for me. I am able to generate tokens. Can you also guide me on integrating wso2is server with wso2 api manager to use these tokens for API consumption?

Comment: You can refer to this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager (in the place of key manager you can use IS)

Answer (score 0):

I have used a custom grant type and solved the issue for getting token. But
I am not able to consume my APIs using this token. I need to create a user on wso2 and subscribe to the API and get token from there in order to consume the APIs. Then what good is the token that i recieved through federated auth?